# How to use a global Style in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I want to use a global Style in WP7, something like:

```xml
<Style TargetType="Button">
//some code here
</Style>
```

The problem is that this code does not seem to work in WP7.

I know how to add x:Key to the Style and after that how to reference it as a StaticResource, but this is not my case. I want a global Style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to use Implicit Styles in WP7.

If so then have in mind that: *Implicit Styles* are a feature of Silverlight 4 (and WPF): Windows Phone 7 is based on Silverlight 3+(with a few Silverlight 4 features added).
Since there’s no *Implicit Styles*  in Silverlight 3 this mean that there is no way to use them in Windows Phone 7 as well.

So, if you want to implement some kind of global Style in WP7, I would suggest that you try the approach with StaticResource as **Matt Lacey** suggested.

Answer (score 8):

If I create an application wide (global) style like this:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyTextNormalStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then I can refer to it like this:

```xml
<TextBlock Text="some text" Style="{StaticResource MyTextNormalStyle}" />
```

Comment: As I explain precariously I know how to do this with StaticResource, but I need a global Style so that all my button us the same style without the need of setting any StaticResource.

Comment: Do you need to do data binding on the phone page for this to work?

Answer (score 1):

In WP7 Mango it supports the implicit styling feature. In mango MS upgraded silvelight 3 to silverlight 4. So it works perfectly

try this link : http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-7-Mango-Implicit-Styles

Answer (score 0):

If you want all your buttons to use the same style, you will have to create a base button class that implements the style then inherit all your buttons from that.

You can do this with a user control or a custom control. A user control is probably easier.